# django-rest-framework: how to represent many-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I'm building a django application, with a rest api, where users can subscribe to feeds.

My model looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, # standard django user
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )

    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(Feed, related_name="subscribers")

class Feed(models.Model):
    # These feeds are read-only for the subscribers
    pass
```

Explained in English:

> Each user has a profile. These profile can subscribe to feeds. The
>   feeds can only be subscribed to, they can't be created or updated by
>   the users.

I want to expose a rest endpoint to create, read, update and delete subscriptions for the current user. Of course, I'd love to use the generic views, a `ListCreateAPIView` and a `RetrieveUpdateDeleteAPIView`, but I can't figure out how to make the correct serializers and querysets to make this easy to use.

I ended up with `/me/subscriptions/` returning a list of Feeds directly, but then the `POST` is weird because it would create a feed instead of creating a subscription.

I'm confused... Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: user profile based on `request.user`? for example  `GET` `/subscriptions/` should return subscriptions `Feed` for that user and `POST` should create a mtm link to that user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `ModelViewSet` and override `create` method:

views.py:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets


class FeedViewSet(serializers.ModelViewSet):  

    serializer_class = FeedSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # show an only related Feed objects to a request.user
        profile = request.user.profile
        return Feed.objects.filter(subscribers=profile)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = request.data.get('pk')
        profile = request.user.profile
        feed = Feed.objects.get(pk=pk)
        profile.subscriptions.add(feed)
        return Response('subscription feed updated!', status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) 

    # list will work by default
    # other methods like update, delete, retrieve 
    # you could set with NOT_IMPLEMENTED status
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_501_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
```

urls.py:

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('subscriptions', FeedViewSet, base_name='subscription')
```

Now you'll have an endpoint for updating subscriptions of `Profile` based on a `request.user`. `GET` to `/subscriptions/` will show all `Feed` objects filtered by `request.user` and `POST` with data `{'pk': <Feed_pk>}` to `/subscriptions/` will create a link between `Feed` and `Profile`.

Comment: That sounds like a sensible solution. But I'm wondering if it wouldn't be easier / less code if I defined a through object in my many-to-many relationship, and then expose that if at all possible.

Comment: @aspyct there is no difference, with through you will still need to override a `create` method, because your purpose is creating link instead of creating object